# How to check if any of the strings in a column match with any string in column in another data table

Tags: r, stringr

I have two data.tables

```
fruit <- c("apple", "banana", "pear", "pineapple")
no <- sample(4L)
fruitDT <- data.table(fruit,no)

fruit2 <- c("apple is a fruit", "orange is a color", "pear is pear", "pine is also a tree")
takeThisOne <- sample(4L)
fruitDT2 <- data.table(fruit2,takeThisOne)

fruitDT

     fruit no
1:    apple  3
2:   banana  2
3:     pear  1
4: pineapple  4

fruitDT2

                fruit2 takeThisOne
1:    apple is a fruit           3
2:   orange is a color           4
3:        pear is pear           2
4: pine is also a tree           1
```

I want to extract the value of takeThisOne column if any of the values in fruit2 match (partially) with any of the values in fruit column from fruitDT.

Expected result

```
apple 3
banana NULL
pear 2
pineapple NULL
```

I was going to use a combination of lapply on str_detect and a for loop for this but wondering if a better way exists?

Comment: `fruitDT2[ fruit2 %in% fruitDT$fruit, takeThisOne ]`

Comment: Or use `grepl()` if you have extra text like your example (although your code doesn't generate the `fruitDT2` you displayed). `fruitDT2[grepl(paste(fruitDT$fruit, collapse="|") , fruitDT2$fruit2), takeThisOne ]`

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and show the expected result. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `fruit` we can use `grep` and return the first entry in `fruitDT2` which matches.

This is a base R approach but using `data.table` syntax since you already have one.

```
library(data.table)

fruitDT[, TakeThisOne := sapply(fruit, function(x) 
                             fruitDT2$takeThisOne[grep(x, fruitDT2$fruit2)[1]])]
fruitDT

#       fruit no TakeThisOne
#1:     apple  3           3
#2:    banana  2          NA
#3:      pear  1           2
#4: pineapple  4          NA
```

Answer (score 1):

With *my* sample data (since it is random),

```r
set.seed(42)
fruit <- c("apple", "banana", "pear", "pineapple")
# no <- sample(4L)
# fruitDT <- data.table(fruit,no)
# fruit2 <- c("apple is a fruit", "orange is a color", "pear is pear", "pine is also a tree")
# takeThisOne <- sample(4L)
# fruitDT2 <- data.table(fruit2,takeThisOne)
fruitDT
#        fruit no
# 1:     apple  1
# 2:    banana  4
# 3:      pear  3
# 4: pineapple  2
fruitDT2
#                 fruit2 takeThisOne
# 1:    apple is a fruit           2
# 2:   orange is a color           4
# 3:        pear is pear           3
# 4: pine is also a tree           1
```

I believe that this is correct:

```r
fuzzyjoin::regex_right_join(fruitDT2, fruitDT, by = c("fruit2" = "fruit"))[,c("fruit", "takeThisOne")]
#       fruit takeThisOne
# 1     apple           2
# 2    banana          NA
# 3      pear           3
# 4 pineapple          NA
```